# SQL JOIN on foreign key that is not equal to primary key

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys, sql-server-2017

I don't exactly know how to phrase the question properly but I'm utterly confused. We have a test-exam and one of the questions is:

> Sort actors descending according to the amount of movies they have
>   appeared in. Show only the first name, the last name and the amount of
>   action movies they have played in. (Note: Unfortunately all actors
>   that have appeared in action movies have all appeared in the same
>   amount).

The correct answer is displayed as following:

```
SELECT 
    Actor.FirstName, Actor.LastName, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    Category 
JOIN 
    Film_Category ON Category.CategoryId = Film_Category.CategoryId
JOIN 
    Film on Film.FilmId = Film_Category.CategoryId
JOIN 
    Film_Actor on Film_Actor.FilmId = Film.FilmId
JOIN 
    Actor ON Actor.ActorId = Film_Actor.ActorId
WHERE 
    Category.Name = 'Action'
GROUP BY 
    Actor.FirstName, Actor.LastName
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

This query returns:

```
JOHNNY  CAGE    64
ROCK    DUKAKIS 64
CHRISTIAN   GABLE   64
PENELOPE    GUINESS 64
MARY    KEITEL  64
OPRAH   KILMER  64
WARREN  NOLTE   64
SANDRA  PECK    64
MENA    TEMPLE  64
LUCILLE TRACY   64
```

The line that confuses me is the second JOIN:

```
JOIN Film on Film.FilmId = Film_Category.CategoryId
```

What does comparing `Film.FilmId` to `Film_Category.CategoryId` do as it's not a foreign key to that table? I even wonder if the answer is correct because when I enter the query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Category.Name), Category.Name 
FROM 
    Film_Category 
INNER JOIN 
    Category ON Category.CategoryId = Film_Category.CategoryId 
GROUP BY 
    Category.Name 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(Category.Name);
```

I get:

```
64  Action
66  Animation
68  Documentary
```

So, presumably all actors appeared in all action movies? Could anybody please help me with this because I have an exam coming up very soon and I'm lost!

Comment: FKs & other constraints are not needed to query. (Their presence just means some expressions return the right result that otherwise wouldn't.) What matters & is needed is what the tables mean, ie what a row says when in a table. But common sense says you do not want rows made from rows having a film id equal to a category id. PS The specification asks for sorting per number of movies an actor has appeared in. But the code sorts per number of action movies they've appear in.

Comment: Is this the correct result value for the values of the input tables? Please give a [mcve]. (That is going to involve example data with less than 66 action movies per person. Because it is going to involve data you & we can easily reason about & check with.) (And the code should not involve irrelevant tables just because they're in an ERD.) (And an ERD should not involve tables irrelevant to the code.) PS Include text as text, not images/links. Images should only facilitate text or give what text cannot, not replace it. Make your post self-contained. (Given DDL an ERD is generally redundant.)

Comment: PS If two actors can have the same name, that query is also wrong. Also lots of appropriate PK/UNIQUE declarations are missing. (Why do you think that query is supposed to be correct?) PS A sensible restriction would be Film.FilmId = Film_Category.FilmId`--but as  Gordon Linoff says Film is "not needed" & in this query inner joining with it is wrong--that returns a row for every actor & each of their films & each of its categories, and the count per actor of action films among those rows is not what you want.

Comment: @philipxy Sorry for the late reply, I didn't get any notifications strangely enough. Retrospectively it didn't make any sense to me either but I'm just learning and my professor provided that answer hence it was so confusing to me. Thanks you for your replies, reading all answers and your replies have given me more perspective than the answers provided by my teacher, sadly enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is not correct.  Based on the ER diagram, it should be:

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName, COUNT(*)
FROM Category c JOIN
     Film_Category fc
     ON c.CategoryId = fc.CategoryId JOIN
     Film_Actor fa
     ON fa.FilmId = fc.FilmId JOIn
     Actor a
     ON a.ActorId = fa.ActorId
WHERE c.Name = 'Action'
GROUP BY a.FirstName, a.LastName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Note that the `Film` table is not needed.  That said, I think the answer to the question is:

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.Name = 'Action' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_action
FROM Category c JOIN
     Film_Category fc
     ON c.CategoryId = fc.CategoryId JOIN
     Film_Actor fa
     ON fa.FilmId = fc.FilmId JOIn
     Actor a
     ON a.ActorId = fa.ActorId
GROUP BY a.FirstName, a.LastName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

The question says to order by *all* films but to only show the counts of *action* films.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My apologies for the late reply, normally I get notifications for provided answers but I didn't receive any strangely enough. The query was provided by my professor but it caused a lot of confusion for me, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

Let Check 'JOHNNY CAGE'

```
SELECT Actor.FirstName, Actor.LastName, COUNT(*) As AllPlayed
        FROM Film
        JOIN Film_Actor on Film_Actor.FilmId = Film.FilmId
        JOIN Actor ON Actor.ActorId = Film_Actor.ActorId
    Where FirstName ='JOHNNY' And LastName = 'CAGE'
    GROUP BY Actor.FirstName, Actor.LastName
```

Result : JOHNNY CAGE 29

Johny was at 29 films at all, nor in 64 Action films

Then your query s wrong, Try changing

```
JOIN Film on Film.FilmId = Film_Category.CategoryId
```

with

```
JOIN Film on Film.FilmId = Film_Category.FilmId
```

....

```
SELECT Actor.FirstName, Actor.LastName, COUNT(*)
FROM Category JOIN Film_Category ON Category.CategoryId = Film_Category.CategoryId
              JOIN Film on Film.FilmId = Film_Category.FilmId
              JOIN Film_Actor on Film_Actor.FilmId = Film.FilmId
              JOIN Actor ON Actor.ActorId = Film_Actor.ActorId
WHERE Category.Name = 'Action'
GROUP BY Actor.FirstName, Actor.LastName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```